# Multi-tenant database : create .BAK file for single tenat

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration, database-backups

In my application I use multi tenant design in my SQL Server database.

My question is: what if one of my customer comes and say, I want my own data as a backup file, how can I create backup file for just that tenant?

Is there is any way to do that?

Do I need any 3rd party tool? Can I do this in a .NET console application?

Comment: Create all the objects in the database into a new database, `INSERT` all their data into the other database as well as any tenant-agnostic data, and then `BACKUP` that database. As any such process would be bespoke, you would need to create your own bespoke process to do this.

Comment: I would say that is not an option. Almost always the database is application specific, not something you offer to a customer in the form of a backup. If the customer wants a specific set of data then develop a feature to export that specific set of data (like user data or order history etc). That is almost always what they (a customer) wants in the long run anyways.

Comment: Short answer - there is simply no direct mechanism to create a true backup of just one client's data. You would need to export all the relevant information to a new database and make a backup of that new database. That should have been part of your disaster recovery plan that YOU implement for customers. A customer should have the ability to roll back to a particular point-in-time in the production database which you host and manage. Doesn't seem like you planned for that.

Comment: Unless you use one database per tenant, what you want is impossible. Tenants are an application concept. The database knows nothing about them. SQL Server backups are actual physical backups of the data files, not data exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I create backup file for just that tenant?

There is no way to do this without running an ETL job either to extract the tenant's data, or to remove the other tenants' data from a restored copy of the database.

This is one of the (many) reasons why you should favor using a database-per-tenant architecture.

Comment: But what if I want to add another column to X table, should I do alter Table X for every tenants Database ?
Can I just alter every table with one Update-Database using migrations ?

Comment: Each tenant gets their own version.  You have to automate the deployments, but you no longer have to update all tenants in a single deployment, which is actually a really useful capability.  EG you can onboard a new tenant to a brand new version before it's rolled out to the other tenants.